# Accessing Jquery object [] and get error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in Jquery, I can't access the elements within the Jquery object.

```
var iconNumber=$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td').length;    // 8 
var iconNumber=$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td')[0].width(); // error
$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td').get(0).after(iconArrow);  // error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you index into a jQuery object, you get the *raw* DOM element at that position, not a jQuery wrapper for it. And that's true of the `get` function as well. (In fact, unless you use a negative index, `get` really just turns around and does `[]` for you; with negative indexes it does a bit more work.)

If you want the *width* of the first element (I assume `with` was meant to be `width`), by default that's what you get if you call it on a set:

```
var iconNumber=$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td').width();
```

Even though there may be more than one element in that set, in general jQuery's "get" operations act on the *first* element in the set. (The API is assymetrical; "set" operations act on the whole set.)

If you wanted the width of the *second* element:

```
var iconNumber=$($('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td')[1]).width();
```

Or making the steps clearer:

```
var rawSecondElement = $('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td')[1];
var wrapperForIt = $(rawSecondElement);
var getItsWidth: wrapperForIt.width();
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a DOM element shouldn't have a `with()` method, which should cause a...

> `undefined` is not a function.

...error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var iconNumber=$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td')[0].with();
```

there's no `with()` method in jQuery, maybe you mean `width()`

```
$('#tblFeedControlBar').find('td').get(0).after(iconArrow);
```

after `.get(0)` you get the dom node (not a jQuery object) so you cannot chain another jQuery (`after()`) method

Comment: `get()` shouldn't return a jQuery object.

Comment: `get(0)`, as I wrote, returns a DOM node reference

Comment: It won't have an `after()` method.

Comment: er... my post ends with _so you cannot chain another jQuery (after()) method_